# how to check if a non-modal dialog is already launched

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-3.5, non-modal

My application launches a non-modal dialog on a button click. If user clicks on that button again, I would like to do a check if that form is already running and wonder if its possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Application.OpenForms Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<YourNonModalFormType>().Any())
   // one is already opened
```

If you want to close this form:

```
var form = Application.OpenForms.OfType<YourNonModalFormType>().FirstOrDefault();
if (form != null)
{
    // launched
    form.Close();
}
```

Comment: thanks. If its already launched, can I close it through this way?

Comment: Actually i am using .net 3.5. Seem like it cannot be utilized in my code. Any other ways of doing it?

Comment: i guess i can always loop through the Application.OpenForms collection and compare its type with that of my non-modal form type

Comment: Are you just missing a `using System.Linq;` ?

Comment: @PaulSnow yep, sorry was busy. And yes, sgmoore is right - LINQ is available since .NET 3.5

Comment: Is there a way to do a helper function out of this? How do i parameter the type/class of the form?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to manually declare a variable to track your form instance:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Form2 f2 = null;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (f2 == null || f2.IsDisposed)
        {
            f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            f2.Close();
        }
    }

}
```